# How can I get data from a transmission?

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, express, ejs

I want to know how I can get the names of the songs from a music stream (more specific to these streams "https://stream-27.zeno.fm/0r0xa792kwzuv?zs=of2rNL4EQaKONauS-rWZdQ, https://stream-61.zeno.fm/0r0xa792kwzuv?zs=SyKyJJtSQvSmEQObk_ymow, http://strm112.1.fm/dubstep_mobile_mp3, http://gene-rgton.ice.infomaniak.ch/generations-rgton.mp3, [https://streams.ilovemusic.de/iloveradio21.mp3"](https://streams.ilovemusic.de/iloveradio21.mp3%22)).
I tried to use an npm module but I get the "cors" thing and the truth is that I am quite new to what is backend. My question is if you can get the names with "fetch" from javascript.
I would appreciate your responses.

I tried this where the server starts, the thing is that it gives the name but it is not updated when the song that is playing ends

```
const { Parser } = require('icecast-parser");

let name;
const radioStation = new Parser({ url: 'http://strm112.1.fm/dubstep_mobile_mp3' });
   radioStation.on('metadata', (metadata) => {
   name = metadata.get('StreamTitle')
});

app.get("/", (req, res) => {
res.render("index", { song: name }); 
});
```

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me, see if it works for you. https://github.com/adoboligh1/zeno.fm_Player
adoboligh1 / zeno.fm_Player

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).